# What about a "newest" tab on answers?

Tags: feature-request

Sometimes I think the newest answers *could be* some kind of

`Wow!! This is awesome!! How is it possible that no one ever figured this out?!`

Or simply when there is so many answers...

---

Anyways, here is my suggestion:

[image]

Comment: Did you try that "active" tab? Because thats *almost* the same thing.

Comment: Why would you prefer that to the "active" tab?

Comment: If you really need, you could sort by "oldest" and browse in reverse order, from last page forward.

Answer (score 2):

I think the `active` tab would suit your needs.  Although it's does show any activity done to an answer, it's for the best, because the answer could have been altered in regards to the question to include more information.